# Spring webflux deployed in tomcat gives 404

Tags: spring-webflux, tomcat8

Deployed a spring boot application as war(due to unavoidable constraint to follow the same in organization) having spring-boot-starter-webflux. he application starts in tomcat, but the rest endpoint returns 404 while testing in postman.
Added following dependencies:
spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client
spring-boot-starter-security
spring-boot-starter-webflux